# Optimize performance of loop

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I've been profiling a bottleneck in my code (a function shown below) that gets called several million times. I could use tips on increasing the performance. The `XXXs` numbers were taken from [Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy).

Compiled with visual studio 2013, `/O2` and other typical release settings.

`indicies` is typically 0 to 20 values, and other parameters are the same size (`b.size() == indicies.size() == temps.size() == temps[k].size()`).

```
1:          double Object::gradient(const size_t j, 
2:                                  const std::vector<double>& b, 
3:                                  const std::vector<size_t>& indices, 
4:                                  const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& temps) const
5:  23.27s  {
6:              double sum = 0;
7:  192.16s     for (size_t k : indices)
8:  32.05s          if (k != j)
9:  219.53s             sum += temps[k][j]*b[k];
10:      
11: 320.21s     return boost::math::isfinite(sum) ? sum : 0;
13: 22.86s  }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for the tips guys. Here were the results I got from the suggestions:

[image]

I found it interesting that switching to `cbegin()` and `cend()` had such a large impact. I guess the compiler isn't being as smart as it could there. I'm happy with the bump, but still curious if there's more room here through unrolling or vectorization.

For those interested, here my benchmark for `isfinite(x)`:

```
boost::isfinite(x):
------------------------
SPEED: 761.164 per ms
TIME:  0.001314 ms
   +/- 0.000023 ms

std::isfinite(x):
------------------------
SPEED: 266.835 per ms
TIME:  0.003748 ms
   +/- 0.000065 ms
```

Comment: Since this is very small piece of code, you may try to do inline.

Comment: J never changes, so if you flip the temps vector around, you can hoist the accessing of J out of the loop.

Comment: Transposing temps would also make it vastly more cache-friendly.

Comment: @tzaman Depends on how crazily indices bounces around, but that could be solved by sorting. Edit, actually no it helps either way. Sorted would just help more.

Comment: try to transpose `temps[k][j]` (that is, use `temps[j][k]` instead). This you jump always to the next memory location (and not a possibly large stride). [Has been said before]

Comment: Silly question but just to check, is the functions boost::math::isfinite() really necessary? Next, maybe you can avoid the if-statement by looping up to j and loop in another loop from j to end.

Comment: Can you provide us with sample input data? Would like to play around with it myself.

Comment: try compile with fp:fast as this involves floating calculation, by default it is fp:precise. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx

Comment: As Elyasin already asked, can you give us some data? And does the vector indices change every call? If not, it may help to sort them once (or maybe it doesn't...). Next, you can use a 1D vector instead of vector<vector>, however all comes down to try and profile.

Comment: Is every single index in the range [ 0, `b.size()` [ in `indices`? because if it is, you can eliminate the `indices` array and do `for( int i = 0; i < j; ++i ) sum += temps[i][j]*b[i]; for( int i = j+1, end = b.size(); i < end; ++i ) sum += temps[i][j]*b[j];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the conditional will be met (that in every iteration you will meet `k == j`), eliminate the conditional and replace the return condition with a simple conditional store.

```
double sum = -(temps[j][j]*b[j]);
for (size_t k : indices)
     sum += temps[k][j]*b[k];
if (!std::isfinite(sum))
     sum = 0.0;
return sum;
```

Range-based for is still new enough to not always get great optimization. You may also want to try:

```
const auto it = cend(indices);
for (auto it = cbegin(indices); it != end; ++it) {
    sum += temps[*it][j]*b[*it];
}
```

and see if the perf varies.

Comment: Switching to `cbegin` and `cend` seems to have the largest improvement so far. Will update the post with the findings.

Answer (score 4):

There are two points that stick out:

(a) boost::math::isfinite is taking relatively long. If possible, try to establish with other ways that your results are within the valid range.

(b) storing a 2D array as a nested vector is not the fasted way. It would probably be faster to make temp a 1D array and pass the row size as a parameter. For the access to a an element you will have to do the index calculation yourself. But as one of the indices (j) is constant over the loop, you can compute the start element's index before the loop and inside just increment the index 1. That might get you some significant improvement.

Comment: These were great ideas. Improved the performance but not as much as others.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll get a significant performance boost if you rearrange your `temps`. The following code line

`temps[k][j]*b[k]`

iterated through the values of `k` is (at least what I understand it to be) a multiplication if a (transposed) matrix by a vector. Now, accessing an element `temps[k][j]` actually involves reading `temps[k]`, dereferencing it (a pointer to allocated vector), and then reading its `[j]` element.

Instead of using a `vector<vector<double>` you could use an 1-dimensional `vector` Moreover, since this function is your bottleneck, you could store the data in it in a "transposed" way. Means, accessing `temps[k][j]` in a new format turns into `temps[j * N + k]` where 'N' is the range of `j`.
By this you also utilize the cache more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that its possible in your solution, but please consider storing input data so that it feets to CPU cache.
Besides other costs like implicit begin() end() calls which you might optimize in the end, cache misses issues will hurt you always. Do not use pointer to pointer in your perf-critical code.
Please also try

```
for (const size_t& k : indices)
```

to avoid copying. However that could be optimized for you by a compiler.

Comment: It is prefered to pass primitive types by value since copying them is at least as efficient as a reference.

Comment: @MichielUitHetBroek what is the size of a reference?  References do not exist in the same way that primitive value types do: they are an alias.  They can be implemented as pointers, but *need not be*, especially if they aren't being stored in a `struct`.  The advantage of a copy here is that you enforce "you only need to read this once" moreso than anything.

Answer (score 0):

The first relatively simple optimization I'd attempt, is this:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& temps
```

This is potentially all over the place in memory and not cache-friendly whatsoever, as it's basically a dynamic array of dynamic arrays with a separate dynamic array for every single row (or column) of the matrix stored in a potentially completely different place in memory.

If you can create a "Matrix" class which stores the data in a single array (ex: single vector), that could help quite a bit.

The next thing I'd try is this:

```
7:  192.16s     for (size_t k : indices)
8:  32.05s          if (k != j)
9:  219.53s             sum += temps[k][j]*b[k];
```

We can see that 'j' never changes in the loop, so if 'temp' could be transposed in advance (also easy to do if you write a proper Matrix class), you could just access the memory sequentially from left to right and access multiple components of the matrix in a single cache line.

Last but not least, do you really run into infinity or NaN with the inputs you are working with? If the latter, I'd see if I could transfer the NaN check elsewhere in checking the validity of those `temps` arrays (provided you reuse the same ones multiple times). Unless you've already run into failures here or are working with a really mission-critical software, I'd try turning that check into a debug-mode assertion and only handle such an edge case if you actually encounter it in production.